# PostgreSQL select minimum unfinished time if it exists, else maximum finished time - coalesce query results

Tags: postgresql

I would like to write a PostgreSQL query that returns the following, if it is not null:

```
SELECT MIN(time) FROM events WHERE finished = FALSE
```

If it is null, then the query should return the following:

```
SELECT MAX(time) FROM events WHERE finished = TRUE
```

(Optional) If the second query is also null, it would additionally be nice (but not required) to be able to fall back to a default value:

```
SELECT '2021-01-01'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine both queries, omit the `WHERE` clause by moving the condition into the aggregates and use `COALESCE` to get the required result:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    MIN(CASE WHEN finished = FALSE THEN time END), 
    MAX(CASE WHEN finished THEN time END), 
    '2021-01-01'
) FROM events
```